# Linker error when compiling ShareKit

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator, sharekit

I am trying to compile ShareKit for my project, but I'm getting a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTweetComposeViewController", referenced from:
        objc-class-ref in SHKiOS5Twitter.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: hi h2co3 can i get u on skype i am new to iphone development ..sometimes i need help.and thanks for editing my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think firstly u should googled with your error. Just add Twitter Framework

- **yourproject** > **Build Phases** > **Link Binary with Libraris**> **Twitter.framework**.